# How to positively describe somebody who misled you by accident

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider this scenario, of two people talking:

> A: Did you go to the shops? 
> B: No, it was closed even though you said it would be open 
> A: Oh no, I misled you! 
> B: No, you didn't mislead me, you just _____ me.

'A' was mistaken, but they didn't mislead 'B' (intentionally), but made a genuine mistake in trying to help out. I want 'B' to imply the help was appreciated even if it didn't help out in the end.

**To be extra clear**, I am only looking for single word answers. Suggestions of rewording the entire exchange are not valid for this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129215/discussion-on-question-by-pureferret-how-to-positively-describe-somebody-who-mis).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the context, especially given that the rest of the sentence clarifies that there was no malicious intent, the one-word solution "misinformed" would work well. One *can* use "misinform" in a context that implies intentional misdirection, but it doesn't have to carry that connotation.

Comment: Would B say "You misinformed me" ? Given the situation I think it would make sense for B to say "You were misinformed" (A didn't know the shop was closed).

Answer (score 21):

I would say:

> *You just made an honest mistake.*  or
> *You just made a well-intentioned mistake.*

Those seem more appreciative than

> *You just made an unintentional mistake.*

Comment: I think 'I don't think there is an answer' answers should be restricted to comments. OP does not solicit a string longer than a single word. 'Put on the wrong track', 'send on a wild goose chase', 'give someone a bum steer' get progressively less friendly-sounding.

Comment: I removed the comment; however, my answer does not fit the sample the OP provided.

Comment: I always feel compelled to stick to a 'comment' unless I think there is a very important point to be brought out (when with a reasonable question I'll ask OP if an edit is possible, or with a muddled question just edit).

Comment: I tend to think “my statement was well-intended, my mistake was unintentional”  A well-intentioned mistake seems incongruous.

Comment: Perhaps  *What I said was well-intentioned* + *What I said was a mistake* = *a well-intentioned mistake*.

Comment: On Amazon, you can buy a blank notebook with *As long as they are well-intentioned mistakes are not a matter for shame but for learning* on the cover. It seems to be missing a comma, so feel free to misread it. This seems to be an expression we use: [6 Well-Intentioned Parenting Mistakes to Avoid](https://mindsplain.com/6-well-intentioned-parenting-mistakes-to-avoid/).

Comment: Wouldn't _an unintentional mistake_ be redundant? If something is a mistake, you didn't intend to do it.

Comment: @PhilPerry *Mistake* has another meaning: *In predicative use: something chosen through an error of judgement; a badly selected thing, a regrettable choice.* OED. The felon says *Robbing that store at gunpoint was the biggest mistake of my life.*

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that the framing of the question is, er, misleading.

"A: Oh no, I misled you!". A is feeling guilty or insecure, and needs some reassurance. Implictly, A knows that they did mislead you and is admitting to it. What B says will depend a lot on the relationship of B to A. It's not a matter of fitting something into the framework of "No, you didn't mislead me, you just _____ me.".

In fact the heavily downvoted "Australian English" example has this best, but obviously only to a good mate who won't mistake your intent and who shares your vernacular.

In a more formal context, maybe "Don't worry about it" or "No problem".

Answer (score 0):

I personally would say in a casual conversation that "you acted in good faith and to the best of your knowledge", although that would probably strike many as overly formal.

Comment: You could shorten that to "you acted in good faith" without losing any real meaning.

Comment: That is the sentiment I'm after, but condensed down into a single word.

Comment: Very informal, and almost exclusively American English, but how about "goofed". "I went to the shops since you said they'd be open, but it seems you goofed, oh well, I'll go tomorrow!"

Answer (score 0):

As you're looking for a single word, try "mistaken". Thus "You didn't mislead me, you were just mistaken" And, as everyone knows, we all make mistakes.